# Validate user by location JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, gps, location

I am trying to develop a page which has a button that can be pressed. When pressed it should execute some functions, but before execution it should first be validated by location. So whenever a user is in a default set location (region like polygon) the button can be pressed without returning an error. And when not in that location or some other error it should give a warning/error.

What plugin/library/code is best to use for this? Any tips how?

**Thank you!**

Comment: Note: remember that such feature could be at best a safely feature, but it is not a security feature. (so it is ok to warn the user about possible error, but do no trust client side validation (and location).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi YEah but i am not trying to secure the button. The whole section is secured by a pretty secure login system. Essentially, a potential user logs in and can clock in himself, but only at the workplace. You feel me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using html5 you can use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition to get location.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

Once you got location you can use [Google Maps Geometry Library], for Polygon specifically you can use:

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polygon arrays</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example requires the Geometry library. Include the libraries=geometry
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.269},
          zoom: 5,
        });

        var triangleCoords = [
          {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19},
          {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
          {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
        ];

        var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: triangleCoords});

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
          var resultColor =
              google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, bermudaTriangle) ?
              'blue' :
              'red';

          var resultPath =
              google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, bermudaTriangle) ?
              // A triangle.
              "m 0 -1 l 1 2 -2 0 z" :
              google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE;

          new google.maps.Marker({
            position: e.latLng,
            map: map,
            icon: {
              path: resultPath,
              fillColor: resultColor,
              fillOpacity: .2,
              strokeColor: 'white',
              strokeWeight: .5,
              scale: 10
            }
          });
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"
         async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```